# Package php5 have no installation candidate (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt, dpkg, ubuntu-16.04

When i try to install php5 in Ubuntu 16.04 by using following code:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mcrypt
```

I get following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried reinstalling but it does not help.

All this error was encountered after I updated my 15.10 Ubuntu to 16.04

Comment: You can get the answer of this question on below link
http://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04/756186#756186

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with PHP7 as the standard, so there are no PHP5 packages

However if you like you can add a PPA to get those packages anyways:

**Remove all the stock php packages**

List installed php packages with `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "` then remove unneeded packages with sudo aptitude purge your_packages_here or if you want to directly remove them all use :

```
sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

**Add the PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

**Install your PHP Version**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

You can install php5.6 modules too ..

**Verify your version**

```
sudo php -v
```

Based on https://askubuntu.com/a/756186/532957 (thanks @AhmedJerbi)

Comment: i understand that, but is there any way to make this work in php7 itself?

Comment: @SrijanKarki you can just use `sudo apt-get install php7` to install php7, however I don't get what you mean with "a way to make this work in php7". your question was about installing php5, no? otherwise clarify and I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: ya i installed php7 already.  And i also tried doing as said in this link.
[Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache). However, `localhost/phpadmin` page cannot be found. Is there some things that may be causing this error?

Comment: @SrijanKarki — So install PHP Admin. It has nothing to do with PHP other than being written in the language.

Comment: use prefix "php5.6-" instead of "php5-" as on ubuntu 16.04 as well

Comment: Works like a charm.   
You'll need to install `aptitute` .    
Run this to install aptitute: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Answer (score 57):

You must use prefix "php5.6-" instead of "php5-" as in ubuntu 14.04 and olders:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt
```

Comment: This has just rescued me from so much pain and frustration!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed`

Answer (score 34):

If you just want to install PHP no matter what version it is, try PHP7

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

for php7.0 works well for me

Comment: `E: Package 'php7.0-mysql' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Me too was facing same problem while Fetching the Postgress Database values using Php so i resolved it by using the below commands.

Mine PHP version is 7.0, so i tried the below command.

`apt-get install php-pgsql` 
**Remember to restart Apache**.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue as well and solved it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-cli
```

php is now installed. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.