# Package php5 has no installation candidate on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have upgraded my system to ubuntu 16.04 LTS, now I have issue this newer version install PHP 7 and remove the PHP 5, How I can install PHP 5.4 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

and I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5 is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package php5 has no installation candidate
```

Comment: First remove php7 package then try to update system.And then install php5.x

Comment: if you want to run both versions (which i would advise) use something like [PHPBrew](http://123code.co.uk/view/Tutorials/using-phpbrew-to-switch-and-manage-php-versions) to manage them.

Comment: `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` sudo: php5enmod: command not found, why this?

Comment: Finally I kicked off ubuntu(16.04)  and reinstall ubuntu 15.10. This is my sooper dooper solution.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad That is a very poor "solution"! Ubuntu 15.10 was not a LTS (Long-Term Support) release; it reached its end-of-life several months ago, and is no longer receiving any updates, even for security issues.

Comment: @duskwuff I have update some time ago my ubuntu version I was facing number of issues(this version has php 7 and I need php5), anyway I will try for latest version once again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package php5 have no installation candidate (Ubuntu 16.04)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788873/package-php5-have-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with PHP7 ,there are no PHP5 packages.
Remove all php7 packages:

```
sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "
```

New PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Update packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

Check PHP Version:

```
php -v
```