# Function utf8_encode undefined

Tags: php

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed, which comes with PHP 7 by default; but I ended up installing PHP 5.6 as well, and I have apache using 5.6.

When I went to run a project of mine, it told me the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function utf8_encode()

I read through a bunch of posts where others have had this issue, and tried installing different extensions; but nothing has helped.

My understanding, was that that function would be packed with PHP (4,5,7) by default.

Any ideas?

*** Update ***

I did try the following, and it came back false.

```
var_dump(is_callable('utf8_encode'));
```

Here are the installed mods/extensions:

[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: Was your PHP compiled with `--disable-xml`? Check your `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Check what php extensions do you have.

Comment: Remove both versions of php and try installing again. That should solve it.

Comment: I just removed all versions of php, and reinstalled 5.6, but still the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788873/package-php5-have-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You should have a package called `php5-xml` or something similar. This function is part of the PHP XML parser

Comment: Just added the list of mods to the question.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, it's installed but is it enabled? Try a2enmod / check mods-enabled folder to triple check!

Comment: access_compat.load  auth_basic.load  authz_core.load  autoindex.conf  deflate.load  env.load     mime.load         negotiation.conf  php5.6.load    status.conf
alias.conf          authn_core.load  authz_host.load  autoindex.load  dir.conf      filter.load  mpm_prefork.conf  negotiation.load  setenvif.conf  status.load
alias.load          authn_file.load  authz_user.load  deflate.conf    dir.load      mime.conf    mpm_prefork.load  php5.6.conf       setenvif.load

Comment: That's what is in the mods-enabled folder

Comment: Oooh I think I got it. I did `sudo a2enmod xml2enc`, and that fixed it.

Comment: Wahey! Kinda weird it doesn't get enabled by default :|

Answer (score 34, accepted):

on ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Worked on Debian 9

Comment: If you want to install   sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml

Answer (score 6):

The following fixed it:

> sudo a2enmod xml2enc

Comment: Make sure php5.6-xml for PHP 5.6 is installed first.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD try this command

pkg install php71-tokenizer-7.1.25 php71-zlib-7.1.25