# PHP5.3-mysql on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, php-5.3, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed php5.3 (I need this specific version) with:

```
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
./configure
make
make install
```

Now it's working.

For work, I also need to install php5.3-MySQL, php5.3-mbstring and other function of php5.3.

How can I do that? I can't find any PPA or anything that can help me.

P.S. I MUST use this specific version. Do you suggest me to use docker or something like that?

P.P.S No VirtualBox, please no.

Thank you all!

Comment: You're probably going to have to go and find the version for each of those libraries and compile them on your machine. Or ask the person responsible for these bad ideas how they intend you to set all this up.

Comment: the question is: WHY do you have to use this version?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I think the answer is in the question. Php-MySQL ))

Comment: no, that is not even close to anything remotely resembling something similar to an answer. but if i guess right and you want php5.3 because of the mysql_* functions, then you are solving the wrong problem with the wrong solution...

Comment: I use it at work. Some instruction of php5.3 doesn't work in newer version like php5.5 so it's not my fault

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Have You ever heard about such term as legacy code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `./configure` you have a lot of options including `--with-<package-name>`. Type `./configure --help` to get complete list of such options.

In case if package that you searching for isn't in standard options then you probably can install it using `pear` utility which is installed with php when you do `make install`.

Almost the same question (PPA `ppa:ondrej/php` suggested in the answer) but here is version 5.6: [Package php5 have no installation candidate (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788873/package-php5-have-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)

Hope this helps

p.s. Or you can use docker for sure, this is quite simple. Ask me in comments if you need instructions (this will be off topic here).

p.p.s. Also, instead of downloading sources you can clone official php-src repo on github and checkout to specific version (they have convenient bookmarks)