# How to install PHP5 in Ubuntu 16 Virtual Box guest on Windows 10 host?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on virtual machine on virtualbox on windows 10.
I've installed lamp stack through "tasksel" command, but it installed apache2 and php7.

My question is: *How can i install php5 (latest version and all its relative/most used  modules) and set as default php?*

Thank you

Comment: `I accept as answer only a complete list of all command and various settings that i've to perform.` You doesn't sound like a very frendly man who I would like to help... You are the one who should do most of the effort, not the people who want to help you.

Please, just use Google for such a question. Good luck and a happy New Year :)!

Comment: So don't help me :-) I only wrote this because often the answer is very short and not very helpfull. 
Because I'm newbie on linux, for me is important that nothing is overlooked

Comment: This should help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: PHP5.3? I thought you wish him a happy new year...

Comment: not 5.3 but php5.6

Comment: i launched the command sudo apt-get install php5 but the shell says: Package php5 has no installation candidate

Comment: @user25 This should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788873/package-php5-have-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-04
Did take me probably less time to Google for this than typing the question did for you ;).

Comment: @Federkun Your right, changed the edit ;).

Comment: How to set as default php ?

Comment: @user25 http://superuser.com/questions/669312/make-a-certain-software-version-the-default-in-ubuntu

Comment: Don't create a list of demands. Don't come here for coaching. This site requires focused specific technical questions and expects you to do your research to learn the technology you're using. It doesn't sound like you did that. People are not volunteering time here to hold your hand through a whole process we are here to clear up very specific targeted areas of technical struggle where people have done their homework and are really stuck. The way you have phrased it is trollish and offensive and I would recommend deletion of the question unless you edit it & correct  aforementioned problems

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
```

Then install python-software-properties first to avoid some errors that might occur

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then install php

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install php5
```

To switch to different php versions,assuming you are using both `php5.6` and `php7.0`

Using apache you can do

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6  ##To use php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.0   ##To use php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sudo a2dismod php5.6 will let forever php5.6 as default ?

Comment: will be the main until you switch to other version,otherwise uninstall any core existing version